# Вопрос по изменению состояния/ссылки объекта

Tags: java, объекты, методы

Есть следующий код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person("Person #1", 100);
    System.out.println(person);
    newPerson(person);
    System.out.println(person);
}

public static void newPerson (Person person){
    person = new Person("Person #2", 200);
    // person.setAge(200);
}

public static class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Если его запустить то в консоль выведется:

```
Person{name='Person #1', age=100}
Person{name='Person #1', age=100}
```

Не совсем понимаю почему так происходит. Person это объект, соответственно передача в параметр должна происходить по ссылке и если внутри метода я присвою этой ссылке другое значение, то после того как метод отработает эта ссылка будет ссылаться на новый объект, разве нет?
В тоже время, если заменить строку `person = new Person("Person #2", 200);` на `person.setAge(200);`, то в консоль выведет:

```
Person{name='Person #1', age=100}
Person{name='Person #1', age=200} - здесь все логично
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь важно понимать, что когда вы передаёте ссылку в параметры метода, вы на самом деле не передаёте ссылку, а передаёте ее копию.

В итоге у вас получается 2 ссылки которые ссылаются на один объект. Если вы измените в нем возвраст, то все ок.

Но если вы ссылке внутри метода присвоите другую ссылку то фактически вы получите 2 ссылки которые ссылаются на разные объекты. Ваша за пределами ссылаться будет на Person 1, а в методе копия будет ссылаться на Person 2

Answer (score 4):

Область видимости такой ссылки только в пределах самого метода.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете изменять ссылку на объект передаваемый в параметрах метода. Изменять сам объект путем вызова методов - да.